# NSTimer won't invalidate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

Not much code here, but this problem is seriously annoying me!

.h:

```
@interface processController : UIViewController {
         NSTimer *timer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
```

.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector (main) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void)main {
    NSLog(@"testing");
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
```

The weird thing is, when I fire this code:

```
ViewController *main = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:main animated:YES];
```

and switch views, the timer keeps firing! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is not called when the view is removed from the screen but **only** when a memory warning is received by the application. It's not called when the UIViewController is deallocated either. From Apple's documentation:

> When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s
>   views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from
>   memory. This method is called after the view controller’s view has
>   been released and is your chance to perform any final cleanup. If your
>   view controller stores separate references to the view or its
>   subviews, you should use this method to release those references. You
>   can also use this method to remove references to any objects that you
>   created to support the view but that are no longer needed now that the
>   view is gone. You should not use this method to release user data or
>   any other information that cannot be easily recreated.

You most likely meant to use `viewWillDisappear`

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
```

You probably want to start your timer in the viewWillAppear: as viewDidLoad is called as soon as the controller's view property is accessed. Not nercessarely when the view is shown.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(main) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

I'd recommend reading the discussions for viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload as well as viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear from the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes, it's important to note that viewDidUnload is not even called when your VC is deallocated, it's actually *only* when your VC is *still around*, but your view is offscreen, and then the OS sends low-memory (or similar situation). In my experience this is only once I am 2 or 3 levels deeper in a navigation hierarchy and simulate low memory.

Comment: Thanks @ctrahey for pointing out that I should clarify when viewDidUnload is called. Added Apple's description of the method for more clarity.

Comment: Also, it would be wise to convert all instances -viewDidUnload and -viewDidLoad stuff into -view(Will|Did)Appear: and -view(Will|Did)Disappear: by the time October rolls around. Word to the wise.